# Informations about FT2232H as programmer

Tags: usb, spi, programmer

I was looking on a EVB that use FT2232H chip to program an SPI ram used in second time to programm another device.

My question is, if I copy the circuit that programm this SPI ram and use the same programmer provided by producer of EVB, it will work or FT2232H is a programmable chip with some kind of blocks or periferical selection?

Here's schmatics of USB interface and SPI flash connections:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An FT2232H is not a micro-controler, it has no FLASH memory that holds code. It is configured via its USB interface.

Your circuit does show an expreal SPI eeprom, you might need to put the appropraite content in that eeprom. You can do this via the FT chip, using a PC application.

Comment: Do you think this EEPROM(FTDI) in EVBoards is fabric preprogrammed or it's programmed each time I run my programmer software?

Comment: It is pre-programmed, but you can probably read out the contents of an existing one. It contains USB-related settings like the PID/VID etc. Check the FT2232 documentation.